# Capture group or nothing

Tags: php, regex

I got this regex using with preg_match in php:

```
/^(node|widget|config)(\/[A-Z]+|)+([^\/]$)/i
```

[RegExr](https://regexr.com/3vg4j) as expected says, that it should match for this cases:

- `TYPE/custom/path/to`
- `TYPE`

but not for

- `TYPE/custom/path/to/`
- `TYPE/`

*TYPE can be either node, widget or config*

But using this expression in PHP with preg_match does match e.g. `node`. Some hints how to change my regex to work?

Comment: Sorry guys, the problem is, that RegExr says that my expression matches `node` but in php it does not.

Comment: Your regex in RegExr doesn't match `node` https://regexr.com/3vgaj and it shouldn't.

Comment: I test only strings which are not multiline.

Comment: @revo There is a match, but it's not displayed. But I am really sure it did when I tested around ... can't explain this. I am sorry. Lession leared: don't trust too much regex tester :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
<?php

$pattern = '/^(node|widget|config)(\/[a-z]+)*$/i';

$test_paths = [
    'node',
    'widget',
    'CONFIG',
    'node/custom/path/to',
    'node/',
    'node/custom/path/to/'
];

foreach ($test_paths as $path) {
    printf(
        "- \"%s\" %s the regex.\n",
        $path,
        preg_match($pattern, $path)? 'matches' : 'does not match'
    );
}
```

The test gives the following output:

```
- "node" matches the regex.
- "widget" matches the regex.
- "CONFIG" matches the regex.
- "node/custom/path/to" matches the regex.
- "node/" does not match the regex.
- "node/custom/path/to/" does not match the regex.
```